# Can we use the __global__ to declare variables in a kernel function? what's the difference to __device__ static?

Tags: cuda

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    T t;
    A() = default;
};
template<typename T> __global__ void myKernel(T t){
    __device__ static A<T> a[256];//can I code like this: __global__ A<T> a[256];
    t+=t;
    printf("val: %d\n", t);
}

int main() {
    myKernel<<<1,1>>>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

`__global__`  to declare variables can be run without error. I'm not sure it's correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure it's correct or not.

It's not correct.  There is no description of `__global__` for variable declaration in [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#variable-memory-space-specifiers).

> `__global__` to declare variables can be run without error.

Sure, you don't get an **error**, but you do get a ***warning***:

warning: attribute "`__global__`" does not apply here

We can surmise based on that warning, that if you use this incorrect usage, the variable so decorated will be treated as if it did not have that decoration.  In your case, that would make it a thread-local variable declaration.

Comment: thinks for your answer, i get it